# how to declare input date in eclipse android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, date, android-asynctask

i want input date, but i dont know how to declare date in eclipse android

this my code

```
EditText txtdate;
```

and then

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_lelang);
txtdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
```

this code my asynctask thread

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", txtdate.getText().toString()));
```

where im write code declare txtdate (Date) ?

Comment: Does it print date in your `EditText`?

Comment: but it doesnt work, in eclipse date make EditText, i think must declare it

Comment: will you add your complete source code ?

Comment: ok. Create a local string inside `doinBackground` and get edittext's value and use that string for `if else` statements and then put them in json.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.lelangifan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.lelangifan.Daftar;
import com.example.lelangifan.ServiceHandler;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FormLelang extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText txtjudul;
    EditText txtharga;
    EditText txtdate;
    Button btncreate;
    JSONArray tag_besar;
    int success = 0;
    int cek_username = 0;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    private static String url ="http://172.16.10.14/mobile_lelang/create_lelang.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_lelang);

        txtjudul = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtjudul);
        txtharga = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtharga);
        txtdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        btncreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncreate);
        btncreate.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.daftar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(view == btncreate){
            new createJson().execute();
        }
    }

    class createJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        Integer form_cek = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(txtjudul.getText().toString() == null)
            {
                alert.showAlertDialog(FormLelang.this, "Info", "Isi Judul", false);
                //T_nama_d.focusSearch(0);
                form_cek = 1;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(txtjudul.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                form_cek = 1;
            }
            else if(txtharga.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                alert.showAlertDialog(FormLelang.this, "Info", "Harga Kosong", false);
                form_cek = 1;
            }
            else if(txtdate.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                alert.showAlertDialog(FormLelang.this, "Info", "Isi Limit Date", false);
                form_cek = 1;
            }

            if(form_cek == 0){
                //Log.d("Form->",String.valueOf(form_cek));

                            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
                            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("judul", txtjudul.getText().toString()));
                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("harga", txtharga.getText().toString()));
                            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", txtdate.getText().toString()));


                            //param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jenis_kelamin", T_jeniskelamin_d.getSelectedItem().toString()));

                            String jsonstrr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST,param);

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonobjj = new JSONObject(jsonstrr);

                                tag_besar = jsonobjj.getJSONArray("data");

                                for(int j = 0; j < tag_besar.length();j++){

                                    JSONObject cc = tag_besar.getJSONObject(j);
                                    success = cc.getInt("success");
                                }

                            }
                 catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            if(form_cek == 0){
                    if(success == 1){
                        alert.showAlertDialog(FormLelang.this, "Info", "Data Berhasil Disimpan", true);

                        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(setupIntent, RESULT_OK);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(FormLelang.this, "Info", "Data Gagal Disimpan", false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```